# Working with video instead of camera input for ARCore in Android

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

Does the ARCore SDK allow to configure the video source as the input for processing to others than the embedded cameras? Similar functionality is available in [Wikitude](https://www.wikitude.com/external/doc/documentation/5.2/androidnative/inputpluginsapi.html) and [ARToolkit](https://archive.artoolkit.org/documentation/doku.php?id=2_Configuration:config_video_capture) for instance, where the camera input can be replaced by custom video frames from other sources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that there is such option. Remember that ARCore is using not only frames from camera but also position of your device as one set of input data. When you will push the video frames as a source of what app see it will not correspond with the position. This will probably be cause of situation where your app will not be able to map the world.

Remember that ARCore is not working only based on the camera/vide but it combines all other elements like gyroscope or accelerometer

Comment: But can all this data be recorded into a new file format(all the gyroscope, accelerometer and camera frames) so that AR core can take that as input and not a live camera feed?